# I make something wrong at the input of CSV

Tags: java, csv, oop, model-view-controller, java-8

I want to ask what i make wrong in csv.
I have an userinput that is "set" and I wanna "get" it into my CSV-File, but it still does not work.
That is my Method where the User take his Input in. It is in the class "auswahlMenue"

```
public void transaktionslisteEinlesen() throws TransaktionIOException{

    System.out.println("Transaktionsliste einlesen");

    // Einlesen von lokalen Attributen
    String beschreibungstext = MeineEingabe.erfasseString("Beschreibungstext: ");
    double betrag = MeineEingabe.erfasseDouble("Betrag:");
    LocalDateTime localdatetime = LocalDateTime.now();
    String transaktionsart = MeineEingabe.erfasseString("Transaktionsart:");
    String iban = ibangen.generate();


    /*
     * Abspreichern der lokalen Attributen in den Konstruktor der Klasse
     * Transaktion
     */
    Transaktion transaktion = new Transaktion();

    transaktion.setIban(iban);
    transaktion.setBeschreibungstext(beschreibungstext);
    transaktion.setBetrag(betrag);
    transaktion.setTart(transaktionsart);
    transaktion.setZeitStempel(localdatetime);

    TransaktionCsv transCSV = new TransaktionCsv();
    transCSV.schreibTransaktionZeilenweiseRaus("transaktion" konto.getTransaktionListe());
    konto.addTransaktion(transaktion);
    System.out.println("\nTransaktionsliste wurde eingelesen!");
}
```

This is the Method that i call. I open manuell the file from my project to check.

```
public void schreibTransaktionZeilenweiseRaus(String dateiname, ArrayList<Transaktion> transaktion) throws TransaktionIOException 
{
    File datei = new File(dateiname);
    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(datei));
        for (Transaktion transaktion1 : transaktion) {
            out.write(transaktion1.getIban() + ";" +transaktion1.getZeitStempel() + ";" +transaktion1.getTart() + ";" + transaktion1.getBeschreibungstext() + ";" + transaktion1.getBetrag() + ";\n");
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new TransaktionIOException("Datei existiert nicht.");
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        throw new TransaktionIOException("Datei kann nicht geschrieben werden.");
    }
}
```

This Methode is reading the Transaktion Line-wise.

```
public ArrayList<String> liesTransaktionZeilenweiseEin(String dateiname) throws TransaktionIOException 
{
    ArrayList<String> zeilen = new ArrayList<String>();

    File datei = new File(dateiname);
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(datei));
        String zeile = null;
        while ((zeile = in.readLine()) != null) {
            zeilen.add(zeile); 
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new TransaktionIOException("Datei existiert nicht.");
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        throw new TransaktionIOException("Datei kann nicht gelesen werden.");
    }

    return zeilen;
}
```

The last one search a Transaktion in the CSV-File

```
public ArrayList<Transaktion> ermittleTransaktionAusCsv(ArrayList<String> zeilen) throws TransaktionCsvFormatException {
    ArrayList<Transaktion> transaktion = new ArrayList<Transaktion>();

    for (String zeile : zeilen) {
        String[] bestandteile = zeile.split(";");
        String iban = bestandteile[0];
        LocalDateTime zeitstempel;
        String transart =  bestandteile[2];
        String beschreibung = bestandteile[3];
        double betrag = 0.0;
        try {
            zeitstempel = LocalDateTime.parse(bestandteile[1]);
           betrag = Double.parseDouble(bestandteile[4]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new TransaktionCsvFormatException();  
        }
        transaktion.add(new Transaktion(iban,zeitstempel,transart,beschreibung,betrag));
    }

    return transaktion;
}
```

I hope you can help me and I am sorry that I post so much code. I post so much because I am really confused.

Best Regards
GreenTea

Comment: So, you have a big wall of code, and it "doesn't work"? That's much too vague. Tell us what you want to achieve, which code you're executing to achieve that, what you expect it to do, and what it does instead. Precisely. And please write code in English so that it's readable by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have complicated your writer. Just use FileWriter. See bellow:

```
String path = "/path/";
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path + dateiname + ".csv");
writer.append("data1;data2;data3");
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

You can see this page is more detailled: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-export-data-to-csv-file-java/

Cheers